# Cordapp migration from open source to enterprise

Tags: corda

We are looking for migration of Corda open source to Enterprise. As part of this migration we need to deploy the Cordapp which was there in the open source to Enterprise. Are there any document available for reference on the challenges or issues faced during Cordapp deployment.

Comment: Yes, the official documentation: https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.8/enterprise/node-operations-upgrading-os-to-ent.html

Comment: And also https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.8/enterprise/app-upgrade-notes-enterprise.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When you want to upgrade from Corda OS to Corda Enterprise you have to consider following items:
1. Corda Node Upgrade 
2. Corda Database Upgrade
3. CorDapp Upgrade
4. Corda Constraint Migration (if you are not using Signature Constraints)

For Corda node and CordDapp upgrade refer to this [blog][1].
For Database migration refer to [this][2] and [this][3] blog.
For Corda Constarint migration refer to [this][4] blog.

There are also some videos which show you how to perform the migration. take a look here-
1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWyJRaoWNhc&t=1186s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs6yGZnDW5g
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BKUUY4Tg20&t=84s
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69un7I-Amwc&t=622s

If you face any difficulty you can get in touch with me on [slack][5].


  [1]: https://medium.com/corda/contract-upgrades-and-constraints-in-corda-425055a9a47f
  [2]: https://medium.com/corda/cordapp-database-upgrade-migration-development-perspective-c2931e28b9b4
  [3]: https://medium.com/corda/cordapp-database-upgrade-migration-production-perspective-5f655838492d
  [4]: https://medium.com/corda/unconstraint-signature-constraint-migration-e95a66789eab
  [5]: https://join.slack.com/t/cordaledger/shared_invite/zt-qg4fft35-ldb97HIf74gImY9XuGybUg
```